# how can I group column by date and get the average from the other column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

From the dataframe below:

[image]

I would like to group column 'datum' by date 01-01-2019 and so on. and get an average at the same time on column 'PM10_gemiddelde'.

So now all 01-01-2019 (24 times) is on hour base and i need it combined to 1 and get the average on column ' PM10_gemiddelde' at the same time. See picture for the data.

besides that, PM10_gemiddelde has also negative data. How can i erase that data in python easily?

Thank you!
ps. im new with python

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: As @FedericoBaù suggest, would be easier to reproduce your scenario if you could copy the dataframe or a subset at least

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieve by:

```
data[['datum','PM10_gemiddelde']].loc[data['PM10_gemiddelde'] > 0 ].groupby(['datum']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column with the average of PM10_gemiddelde using `groupby` along with `transform`. Try the following:

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, start first by removing the negative data:

```
new_df = df[df['PM10_gemiddelde'] > 0]
```

Then, you can create a new column that contains the average value for every date:

```
new_df['avg_col'] = new_df.groupby('datum')['PM10_gemiddelde'].transform('mean')
```